# Calling a function with with an object that randomly chooses elements from a vector

Tags: c++

So what I'm trying to do is put a class object into the function "random".
However, it fails to alter the preassigned value of the variables in the class. Why is this happening? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int racedice;
int genderdice;
int namedice;
int agedice;


class human
{
public:
    // Assignment of variables
    int age;
    string name = "\"NAME UNSPECIFIED\"";
    string race = "UNKNOWN";
    string gender = "UNKNOWN";

    void setrace(string x)
    {
        race = x;
    }
    void setgender(string x)
    {
        gender = x;
    }
    void setage(int x)
    {
        age = x;
    }
    void setname(string x)
    {
        name = x;
    }
    void info()
    {
        cout << "NAME: " << name << endl;
        cout << "RACE: " << race << endl;
        cout << "GENDER: " << gender << endl;
        cout << "AGE: " << age << endl << endl;
    }
};

void random(human obj)
{
    vector<int> agelist;
    agelist.push_back(1);
    agelist.push_back(2);
    agelist.push_back(3);
    agelist.push_back(4);
    agelist.push_back(5);
    agelist.push_back(6);
    agelist.push_back(7);
    agelist.push_back(8);
    agelist.push_back(9);
    agelist.push_back(10);

    vector<string> racelist;
    racelist.push_back("White");
    racelist.push_back("Black");
    racelist.push_back("Asian");
    racelist.push_back("Hispanic");
    racelist.push_back("European");
    racelist.push_back("American");

    vector<string> malenames;
    malenames.push_back("Jim");
    malenames.push_back("Josh");
    malenames.push_back("Jack");
    malenames.push_back("Tim");

    vector<string> femalenames;
    femalenames.push_back("Kimi");
    femalenames.push_back("Mary");
    femalenames.push_back("Julia");
    femalenames.push_back("Olivia");

    vector<string> genderlist;
    genderlist.push_back("Male");
    genderlist.push_back("Female");

    genderdice = (rand() % 2);
    racedice = (rand() % 6);
    namedice = (rand() % 4);
    agedice = (rand() % 10);

    if (genderdice == 0)
    {
        obj.setgender(genderlist.at(genderdice));
        obj.setname(malenames.at(namedice));
    }
    else
    {
        obj.setgender(genderlist.at(genderdice));
        obj.setname(femalenames.at(namedice));
    }

    obj.setrace(racelist.at(racedice));
    obj.setage(agelist.at(agedice));
}

int main()
{
    vector<human> humanlist;
    human *joe = new human;
    human *mary = new human;

    humanlist.push_back(*joe);
    humanlist.push_back(*mary);

    random(*joe);
    random(*mary);

    vector<human>::iterator it;
    for (it = humanlist.begin(); it != humanlist.end(); it++)
    {
        it->info();
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `vector<int> agelist {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`

Answer (score 1):

> However, it fails to alter the preassigned value of the variables in the class.

The parameter `obj` is declared to be passed by value, that means any modification on it inside the function has nothing to do with the argument passed in.

You could change it to pass-by-reference:

```
void random(human& obj)
```

---

There're memory leaks in your code. The 2 objects of type `human` is `new`ed but not `delete`ed at last. The better approach might be:

```
vector<human> humanlist;

humanlist.push_back(human{});
humanlist.push_back(human{});

random(humanlist[0]);
random(humanlist[1]);

vector<human>::iterator it;
for (it = humanlist.begin(); it != humanlist.end(); it++)
{
    it->info();
}

cout << endl;
```

or more briefer:

```
vector<human> humanlist(2); // construct a vector with 2 default-constructed elements

random(humanlist[0]);
random(humanlist[1]);

for (const auto& h : humanlist)
{
    h.info();
}

cout << endl;
```

Note `info()` need(should) be declared as const member function for the code above. It doesn't modify the members of the class.

```
void info() const
{
    cout << "NAME: " << name << endl;
    cout << "RACE: " << race << endl;
    cout << "GENDER: " << gender << endl;
    cout << "AGE: " << age << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: @JackDeeth I just focused on the memory leak issue. Anyway, the code could be improved in many ways, such as we don't need use `push_back` here indeed, and we could use range-based for loop, or `std::for_each`.

Comment: So what is "human{}" inside of the push_back and what does it do? Are there any alternate options i could put inside of the push_back?

Comment: @hindstrust It default construct a temporary `human` and then `push_back` it into the vector. See my edited answer.